# JPA - Mapping multiple OneToOne entities options

Tags: hibernate, oop, jpa

We have an entity called `Enterprise` and some entities that refer and define the type of that an `Enterprise` object, like `Subsidiary`, `Carrier`, `Agent`, `Supplier` and `Client`. Each `Enterprise` object can be of one or more types.

Today we have this mapping based on join columns, that are mapped by each type entity, like for example on `Supplier` we have:

```
 @Entity
 public class Enterprise {
      @Id
      private Integer id;
      ...
      @Column
      private Boolean isSupplier; 
      ...
 }

 @Entity
 public class Supplier {
      @Id
      private Integer id;

      @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name="IDENTERPRISE")
      private Enterprise enterprise;

      // Some other fields specific to suppliers here
      ...
 }
```

And the other entities follow this mapping model, but we are having problems to persist the model and the relationships due to lazy loading and other questions, it became too hard to maintain and it is causing confusion and more mapping problems, for example, suppose that we have another entity called `Invoice` and we need to specify the `Client` and the `Carrier`, some programmers here prefer to make the relation  with `Enterprise` and then use the field value to locate the correct object on service classes, other programmers prefer to make the relation with `Client` or `Carrier` directly and the system is turning into a fruit salad.

I know `@Embeddable` entities, and i know that is probably the best solution, but our database expert said to avoid tables with too many information, with too many fields, and this is what `@Embeddable` will cause.

Maybe inheritance is a good solution, but we don't know how to make this with the given scenario, we have an `Enterprise` that can be both a `Client` and a `Supplier` but JPA needs a discriminator column that identifies the object type.

We are decided to change these entities and make what is needed to use the best mapping strategy possible.

We found [here](http://dextra.com.br/hibernate-onetoone-e-como-conseguir-ou-nao-um-lazy/)¹, on the comments of Jean Merelis, an example of how to do an `@OneToOne` lazy relationship, see below the source in english:

```
 public class Person {
      @Id
      private Long id;

      @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person")
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
      private Address address;
 }

 public class Address {
      @Id
      private Long id;

      @OneToOne(optional=false)
      @MapsId
      @JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      private Person person;
}
```

In this way, we can cascade the persist operations and always refer to the `Enterprise` entity, providing some fields like this:

```
 @Entity
 public class Enterprise {
      @Id
      private Integer id;

      @OneToOne(mappedBy="enterprise", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
      private Supplier asSupplier;
      ...
 }

 @Entity
 public class Supplier {
      @Id
      @Column(name="IDSUPPLIER")
      private Integer id;

      @OneToOne(optional=false)
      @MapsId
      @JoinColumn(name="IDENTERPRISE")
      private Enterprise enterprise;

      // Some other fields specific to suppliers here
      ...
 }
```

So, finally, my question, is this a good choice? If not, can you provide a good example of how to make better?

¹: Sorry for the Portuguese site, but i didn't found an english version of this example.

Comment: Are you using your object model for queries? If you wouldn't then you could stop worrying about things like two-way relationships and composing objects that perhaps do not belong together. What behaviors can you perform on an Enterprise and a Supplier?.

Comment: Yes, i am they for queries. An Enterprise can not exist without one of your subtypes. So the question must be, what types of behaviours differ from a Supplier and an Agent, for example? And the answer is, a Supplier can be used where an Agent can't, for example on an order's traveling details.

Comment: Does [@DiscriminatorFormula](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/discriminatorformula_hibernate_annotation) solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the entity can evaluate to two types at the same type, using discriminator value or discriminator formula, even if i set the id of all objects to the same, hibernate will try to insert one record in the base table for each child table.